# What is the use of class="slds-truncate" in Lightning Web Components?

Tags: lds

Long text field with many lines and truncation will look like this. Even though the text might go on for ages and ages.

Answer (score 4):

Long text will be truncated and ended with an ellipsis (...)
Provides a cleaner output to the user for fields that are long that don't actually need to be shown on the screen being displayed, like a report.

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/truncation/